# I want to create a custom Rule?

Tags: rules, users

I have to create a custom rule . Basically its a site for faculty.Before a faculty is added to site an authentication is done by there ldap server on first time login.After user is authenticated it redirects to site.Each faulty has there own vsite.So issue is that a faculty who has been removed from ldap then his/her vsite must be disabled.
Now is it possible to do it through Rule ??

Comment: What do you mean by "... vsite must be disabled"? Maybe a typo somehow? What happens "After user is authenticated it redirects to site", but the faculty has been removed from ldap for that site, do you get like a page not found, or something else? HOW did you implement the redirect? And what exactly do you want to be disabled: the userid, the redirect, or anything else? What do you have in place already in Drupal to know if such site is disabled or not?  Please EDIT your question to clarify all this (do not add a comment to do so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rules are very important and most common using thing in Drupal. We can create custom rules programmatically using the hook_rules_action_info. There is a useful hook `hook_rules_action_info()` provided by rules api to create custom rules programmatically. Using this We can use our custom functions to perform the actions that we require.

Following is a sample of the hook_rules_action_info implementation

```
function sample_custom_rules_action_info() {
  return array(
    'sample_custom_action' => array(
      'label' => t('Custom Rule Action'),
      'parameter' => array(
        'param1' => array(
          'type' => 'int',
          'label' => t('Sample Label'),
        ),
        'param2' => array(
          'type' => 'commerce_order',
          'label' => t('Sample Label2'),
        ),
      ),
      'configurable' => FALSE,
      'group' => t('sample Custom module action'),
      'callbacks' => array(
        'execute' => 'sample_custom_action',
      ),
    ),
  );
```

- Label for the rule action appears in the Rules interface.
- Parameter that needs to be passed to the custom action function
- A group for this element, used for grouping the actions in the
  interface.
- callbacks are array of custom functions that to be used for this
  action's functioning.

This function has more parameters, but the above are most required ones to create a custom action.

**Video tutorial**

[Creating a Rules Action](https://drupalize.me/videos/creating-rules-action?p=1152)